# Cakephp 3 create folder

Tags: php, cakephp

I`m trying to dynamically create folder inside webroot whit

`$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'imggg');`
but it doesn't for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you receive any error messages?

Answer (score 4):

You should start by reading the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html#folder-api) first. See the `$create` variable and how it's set to false by default? That means that a folder is not "just" created when you fire up an instance of the Folder utility, unless you set the `$create` argument to true, like:

```
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'imggg', true);
```

So, you need to explicity tell Cake you want it to create the folder if it doesn't exist yet.

Alternatively, you can just create a fresh Folder instance and then call the [create](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html#Cake%5CFilesystem%5CFolder::create) method on that:

```
$dir = new Folder();
$dir->create(WWW_ROOT . 'imggg');
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer:-)!!! I try whit <code>$dir = new Folder('imggg', true);</code> Because I was think that www_route is set by defaul